# Getting error "Attempted to index global 'table' (A nil value)" Lua

Tags: lua, pico-8

When I run this code snippet in Lua (using PICO-8 if it helps)

```
a = {}
table.insert(a,1,'foo')
```

I get the error

> Attempted to index global "table" (a nil value)

According to the Lua website, this should work (https://www.lua.org/pil/19.2.html).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `a[1]='foo'` instead.

Comment: @lhf I would use that, but my project requires shifting over values, while  `a[1]='foo' ` overwrites the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lua was unable to resolve the `table` part of `table.insert`. This is most likely because your host environment does not include the table standard library.

As Lua is an "embedded" language, and most of its standard library is optional and may not be available if an environment decides to exclude it.

For PICO-8 in particular:

> PICO-8 does not include the Lua standard library, and instead provides
> a proprietary collection of global functions.

[Source](https://pico-8.fandom.com/wiki/Lua)

Comment: Specifically, you have to use the `add` command here. https://www.lexaloffle.com/dl/docs/pico-8_manual.html#Table_Functions